# VerticalTextAlignment="End" doesn't align my text at the bottom of a <StackLayout>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
             x:Class="Japanese.Templates.HeaderTemplate" 
             x:Name="this" BackgroundColor="#efeff4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" >
        <Label Text="ABC" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

When it runs the text ABC appears at the top of the cell and not the bottom.

Can someone explain to me why it does not appear at the bottom when I use VerticalTextAlighment="End"

I also tried this but it still puts the text at the top of the StackLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
             x:Class="Japanese.Templates.HeaderTemplate" 
             x:Name="this" BackgroundColor="#efeff4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" >
        <Label Text="ABC" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="End" 
        VerticalOptions="End" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: that will just align the text at the bottom of the Label.  If you want the Label to appear at the bottom of the StackLayout, you will need to use VerticalOptions="End"

Comment: I tried: <Label Text="ABC" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               VerticalOptions="End" 
               VerticalTextAlignment="End"  /> but it still puts the text at the top

Comment: Your StackLayout is only as big as it needs to be to contain it's contents.  If you want it to fill the screen, you will need to set it's Fill option, or try explicitly setting a height.

Comment: I want the StackLayout to be 50 high. Can you give an example as an answer with the fill and height set so I can test it out and accept it.   Thanks

Comment: Take a look at FlexLayout, maybe it's a good option for you. You can put the StackLayout inside of it. Also, it's a good idea to change the stacklayout background color so that way you can see where it ends. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

Comment: FlexLayout is the best option for this, thx @CarlosMacMar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ContentPage BackgroundColor="Purple" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test3" x:Class="test3.MainPage">
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label BackgroundColor="Pink" Text="I'm at the bottom!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason,  was the problem that I didn't use "EndAndExpand"?